# authorize user to use REST API through google services

Tags: android, security, single-sign-on, google-sso

I have three actors:

1. (my) RESTful API behind SSL.
2. (my) Android app that has Google "Sign in" button.
3. (my) Web App that allows user register using their Google Account via OAuth.

What I would like to be able to do is this:

1. Generate something when user logs in on the mobile device.
2. Compare that to something else I can generate on the server for that Google Account.
3. If the two pieces match match, give app a newly generated token that it can use in all subsequent API calls for a period of time.

How do I go around doing that? I am reading through OAuth documentation but I am struggling to understand what are these "something" and "something else". Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.

For Google, I send user uid and authorization token that I have obtained in the app by `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()`. On the server, I go to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?fields=user_id&access_token={token}`, where `{token}` is the token I received from my mobile app. If the user_id in OAuth2 response matches the `uid` that was supplied by API and the `uid` matches for some user record in my database, that user is considered authenticated.

For Facebook, I do the same thing, except I use `session.getAccessToken(...)` to obtain the token on the app side and `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token={token}` to verify it with Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are still woking on this, I get to your questing having the same scope than you and facing the same issues and after searching the net (Google, Stack overflow and Google Developers documentation) I've found something tu put my hands on this evening after work that may help others to achieve this feature in their apps:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

But that's not enough, is a good reading but doesn't solve our problems at all.

More usefull readings on this topic should be this (wich says "This quick-start app lets you get started with Google Identity Toolkit on Android in about 30 minutes."):

https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/quickstart#step_2_configure_the_google_identity_toolkit_api

I tried it once but my app and web api wasn't mature enough, I'll try that asap and I'll let you know if I could make it work as expected (as the tipical web aplication example)...

Hope it helps anybody else.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I have actually solved that in my app. Not sure if that's the best way, but it works fine right now.